# How to return object class without creating new one?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, instanceof

I have hierarchy of few classes:
Organism -> Fox,Antelope,Wolf

And i want to create a method that will define what is the class of the given object, without returning new instance of this object.

Something like this:

```
public Organism defineOrganismClass(Organism o) {
        if (o instanceof Antelope) {
            return ...;
        }if (o instanceof Fox) {
            return ...;
        }            //and so on
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. If the object is a `Fox`, then it's already a `Fox`, so why would you need to create a new `Fox` object? What is the method even supposed to do? The return type is the same as the parameter type, so other than simply doing `return o;`, I can't seem to figure out what the purpose is.

Comment: Could you show an example of how you want to call the method, how you want to use whatever it returns, and what *problem you hope to solve* by doing this?

Comment: I've answered this question, but this does seem to be an XY-problem: you are asking X but to accomplish Y. What is it what you want to accomplish by returning the type?

Comment: I'm trying to simplify method that reproduces organisms:
````  

private void reproduce(Organism organism,) {
        Optional<Organism> newlyCreatedOrganism = Optional.empty();

        if (organism instanceof Antelope) {
            newlyCreatedOrganism = Optional.of(new Antelope(getGetWorld()));
            //todo randomly change position of newly created organism
        }
        if (organism instanceof Fox) {
            newlyCreatedOrganism = Optional.of(new Fox(getGetWorld()));
        }
}

````

Comment: Well, using reflection you can also instantiate classes using `Class#newInstance()`, that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can return `Class<? extends Organism>` instead, e.g. `Fox.class`. This will give you the class definition, but no instance. You would not need the `if` statements, just `return o.getClass()`.

It does of course beg the question what you then want to do with that class. Maybe you want to define an enum instead, e.g. `enum OrganismType { ANTELOPE, FOX }` which is easier to operate on.

Comment: Why would you need to use `Fox.class`? Wouldn't simply doing `return o.getClass();` be it? In which case the real question is: What's the point of this method?